# TrueTime Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I am implementing true time flutter library https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/true_time

Getting an error

```
W/DiskCacheClient(26153): Cannot use disk caching strategy for TrueTime.

 CacheInterface unavailable
D/TrueTimeRx(26153): ---- resolving ntpHost : ntp.google.com
W/DiskCacheClient(26153): Cannot use disk caching strategy for TrueTime. CacheInterface unavailable
E/MethodChannel#true_time(26153): Failed to handle method call
E/MethodChannel#true_time(26153): java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to call init() on TrueTime at least once.
```

I get this error with a copy of the code from the readme linked to above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try to use this lib? It uses just dart code, instead of platform channels. https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/ntp

You can get time like this:

`DateTime startDate = await NTP.now();`

Disclaimer: I'm developer of this lib.

Comment: but it is breaking most of the time. Async call keeps awaiting.

Comment: Hmm, Do you have stackTrace? If you submit a bug I will fix it :)

Comment: @knezzz what is main difference between your library and true_time library?

Comment: My package is Dart package and writen purely in dart, so it will work on any platform (web/desktop/mobile/rpi). While true_time is a Plugin package and uses platform specific calls to check time.

Comment: Would be great if your package would work without async, only with 1 time initialization

Comment: Hey @mbartn I was actually thinking of doing this soon but I'm not really sure how I should do this. I'm just afraid what to do if when you init it it still doesen't have init time when you ask for it? I would have to reasearch a bit deeper on how to do that. Any suggestions and/or PR are welcome :)

Comment: Hey @SudhansuJoshi I am having the same problem when implementing the NTP library. Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Hey @OmerCelik Can you share example code where it is breaking for you? You can also report issue to my github, I can check out what is happening :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your code? From the stack trace, it's clear that you did not `init` TrueTime. In the example in https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/true_time , you can see they have the following code

```
// ...
  _initPlatformState() async {
    bool initialized = await TrueTime.init();
    setState(() {
      _initialized = initialized;
    });
    _updateCurrentTime();
  }
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be `time.google.com` as NTP host instead of `ntp.google.com` in `true_time` library. 
you can directly use `true_time.dart` from package and update ntp host to `time.google.com` to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

To get internet time you can use this plugin `ntp: ^2.0.0`

```
import 'package:ntp/ntp.dart';

final int offset = await NTP.getNtpOffset(
        localTime: DateTime.now(), lookUpAddress: "time.google.com");
DateTime internetTime = DateTime.now().add(Duration(milliseconds: offset));
```

Or there are plenty of apis available

```
http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Asia/Kolkata
```

this `GET` api will provide you indian time you can change the time zone according to your need, the result will be like the below `JSON`

```
 {
      "abbreviation": "IST",
      "client_ip": "45.125.117.46",
      "datetime": "2022-02-26T10:50:43.406519+05:30",
      "day_of_week": 6,
      "day_of_year": 57,
      "dst": false,
      "dst_from": null,
      "dst_offset": 0,
      "dst_until": null,
      "raw_offset": 19800,
      "timezone": "Asia/Kolkata",
      "unixtime": 1645852843,
      "utc_datetime": "2022-02-26T05:20:43.406519+00:00",
      "utc_offset": "+05:30",
      "week_number": 8
    }
```